# MissingRegion: could not find region configuration in golang and aws sns

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-sns

I am new to Golang and AWS. I am trying to send SMS using AWS SNS.
I have set Environment variable First then try send SMS.

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=AKIAIOSFODN..
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=wJalrXUtnFEM..
export AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-west-2
```

I tried to debug where i am getting wrong
But always getting error 
**MissingRegion: could not find region configuration**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/sns"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("creating session")
    sess := session.Must(session.NewSession())
    fmt.Println("session created")
    svc := sns.New(sess)
    fmt.Println("service created")
    params := &sns.PublishInput{
        Message: aws.String("testing 123"),         
        PhoneNumber: aws.String("+14445556666"),    
    }
    resp, err := svc.Publish(params)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(resp)
}
```

I am trying to do this since last 2 days.Please help me where i am going wrong.

Comment: `session.NewSession(&aws.Config{Region: aws.String(region)})`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to configure the SDK. To set just the region you would do something like

```golang
sess, err := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
    Region: aws.String("us-west-2")},
)
```

You can see full details on config here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/v1/developer-guide/configuring-sdk.html

Comment: I did this at least region error is not coming but below is coming
caused by: Post https://sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/: dial tcp: lookup sns.us-west-2.amazonaws.com on 192.168.0.1:78: read udp 192.168.0.89:51137->192.168.0.11:53: i/o timeout

Comment: So it needs another region config even after declaring it in env variable?

Comment: aws.String("Welcome: to, { the &Incomprehensible.world: of (:=&Go)!")

Answer (score 14):

The Go SDK does not recognize the env variable `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`
The region can be specified using the `AWS_REGION` name as below

```
export AWS_REGION="us-west-2"
```

The other way is to explicitly pass the region while creating the session as per the answer by [noisewaterphd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56135449/3639687)